# SSRS CROSS Domain Reports Server Authentication

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs

I have a pretty complicated situation at hand, let me try to explain.

I have a SQL Server and a Web Server in a separate domain (lets call it domain A).

SQL Server has the databases for Reporting services, The web server has reporting services installed.

The SSRS also have SSL certificates installed and we are using https protocol to connect to the reports manager.

Now I need to give access to users from domain B to connect to the Reports Manager (report server on Domain A).

The users from Domain B cannot have any logins in the Domain A where the reporting services are installed, I know to access the reports manager I need to add domain logins/groups to the reports manager and assign them appropriate roles to access the reports.

What options do I have (if any) to give access to users from Domain B to connect to a Reports Manager on Domain A?

*Important Note:*

The access to reports server is via NLB with external facing IP, the reports server (web server) or the SQL server does not have any external facing IP

Comment: Can you setup local (non-domain) users on the Reporting Server?

Comment: Yes I have already done that, but the problem is when a user from other domain tries to access the reports manager, how that user will be authenticated? The users access the reports manager by just typing in the url , now even if they do put in the local user details they still keep getting prompts for username and password

Comment: @MaxVernon When I try to login to reports manager using local user credentials from the reports server itself it worked for me , but from the cross domain it doesnt work :( very strange. and I am sorry I have forgot to mention a very important point, The access to reports server is via NLB with external facing IP, the reports server (web server) or the SQL server does not have any external facing IP.

Comment: @MaxVernon I have also tried to connect to Reports Manager from the reports server itself using the NLB url i.e `https://NLB.name.com/Reports` and it prompts me for the username and password, if I used the local username and password it did not work. But if tried to connect to Reports Manager using the local server name it works i.e `https://ServerName/Reports` it is only from the reports server itself.

Comment: I am *speculating*, what you are telling wont work - you need to have trust between the domains. Can you create sql server users with same sids for allowing report execution ?

Comment: Not sure if this would work for you but you may want to check some of the solutions in this article regarding RS anonymous access. . . Since the RS interface isn't external facing then perhaps this could work... otherwise, a trust between domain A and domain B should work just fine then domain A and domain B AD user accounts could authenticate with their own credentail on their domain via security configurations in RS....https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sqlserver/en-US/07032cc9-f447-423e-84d5-96c776888b6b/reporting-services-2008-anonymous-access

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't recommend it but

You have two options:

1. Connect using a domain username & password from network A (everyone
   in network B connecting as DOMAINA/userx)
2. Allowing anonymous access.  (this is inherently dangerous and you would want at a bare minimum to pass something to all of your reports as part of your process for security authentication and probably change the default structure for uploading http://local/reportserver might become http://local/rs)

Comment: But he did state specifically that "The users from Domain B cannot have any logins in the Domain A where the reporting services are installed" so this would leave an anonymous access situation or else setup a domain trust.

Comment: He did. However you will need some form of Alias connection to make between the two domains or you have to allow anonymous.